# Tilde and angle bracket keys are swapped

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I have looked for solutions to this problem quite a bit now, and I haven't found any good answers to it.

This is the layout I am using
[image: Image of keyboard layout]

When pressing the tilde key (the one to the left of 1), it instead outputs an angle bracket, and the layout screen shows that the button to the left of Z is pressed.
The same goes for the opposite, when pressing the angle bracket key (left of Z), it shows that the tilde key is pressed instead.

I have no clue when this started to happen, nor do I know why this happened. I would love for some tips or directions on how to fix this issue as it is quite annoying. This issue is present on any layout, including the US layout, which I normally use.

System information:

OS: Debian Bookworm

DE: Cinnamon/GNOME (issue is present on both)

The computer is a laptop. This issue is only there on the laptop's keyboard, not on any keyboards connected.

Physical keyboard layout is Norwegian

Comment: [This is the Norwegian layout on my KDE system](https://ibb.co/6WbqQhQ)

Comment: @mashuptwice Maybe I should reiterate, especially since I make a discovery. The physical keyboard layout is Norwegian, but this issue is there for all layouts. I normally use the US layout, where the tilde and angle brackets are being swapped. My new discovery is that this issue only exists on the laptop's keyboard, and not any connected keyboards.

Comment: That sounds more like a hardware issue then, could you boot a live USB to make sure that it is not related to your OS?